# Понять что ответ из кеша брезура

Tags: javascript, fetch

Если я делаю запрос
`fetch(url).then(fnAnswer)`
Как мне понять, что ответ взят из кеша браузера или нет?

Comment: Только хидером просить не кешировать. Ещё запросы post не кешируются по умолчанию

Comment: Если не подходит отказ от кеша, то можно хранить переменную в js (например в localStorage), а на сервере в ответ включать какой-то ключ с рандомным значением. И потом проверять - если ключ совпал, значит данные из кеша, иначе актуализируем ключ в браузере (и данные значит не из кеша).

Comment: @PavelGrishaev
Ну вот я пока что точно так же думаю(
Спасибо.
1. Посмотреть заголовки, на сколько кешировать говорит сервер
2. Создать new Map({method, url, timestamp}[])
3. По timestamp очищать старые запросы
4. Следить за закрытием приложения (браузера), чтобы очистить историю
Звучит как костыль

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После ресеча и общения с коллегами я нашел два с половиной рабочих способа:

1. Смотрим на все запросы в performance: 
   `performance.getEntries().filter(item=>item.initiatorType==='fetch')`.
   Если `transferSize === 0` – значит запрос из кеша.
   *(Но поскольку у меня CORS, то этого поля нет вообще)*
2. Использовать уникальный идентификатор, например HTTP ETag. Сохранять его в `new Map` или просто объект.
   (Мне повезло, я его беру из headers)
3. (2.5) Если с ETag не повезло, тогда уже сохраняем полностью информацию о запросе... Например `method+path+getParams`.

Грубый пример того, что сделал я:

```
const queriesHistory = {};

fetch(url).then(responce=>{
    const etag = response.headers.get('ETag');
    if (queriesHistory[etag]){ 
        console.log('Запрос из кеша');
        return;
    }

    // add to history
    queriesHistory[etag] = Date.now();
})
```

Удаление старых запросов:

```
    const ONE_HOUR = 3600000;

    // remove old
    Object.keys(queriesHistory).forEach((key) => {
        if (queriesHistory[key] + ONE_HOUR > Date.now()) {
          delete queriesHistory[key];
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

По идеи, он всегда будет без кэша

Вообще, я бы использовал следующий код(ибо хз что за фетч у тебя там):

```js
const afetch=(_url)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            // cache: false, // можешь убрать коммент
        }).done((r)=>{
            if(!r)r = false;
            resolve(r);
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e.status, e.responseText, e);
            resolve(false);
        });
    });
};

(async()=>{
    let r = await afetch('https://www.google.ru/');
    console.log('response', r);
})();
```

Comment: лет 10 назад, было бы актуально)

Comment: @SultanovShamil почему? +Ажакс не всегда возвращает то что нужно, если пользовать `await перед ним`

Comment: ну как минимум потому что ты предлагаешь подрубить jQuery чуваку, который использует нативный js

Comment: Но все равно спасибо за ответ )